# Entity Framework Code First Layered WPF application

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Anyone know of a layered WPF example application (not web application) using Entity Framework Code First?

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx). I suggest you read the [ADO.Net team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) they have given plenty of tutorials and examples.

Comment: [Here](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/unicornmanager-prism-4-mef-wpf-ef-4-1-code-first-nuget-datavalidation/) is a nice sample with EF 4.1 code first and MEF.